# Can I fix butter (for a sauce) after putting too much mustard in?

Tags: butter, mustard

I'm making sauce for chicken cordon bleu. The butter has shallots, parsley, mustard, salt and pepper. I put too much mustard into the butter. Can I fix this?

Comment: You haven't actually used the sauce yet, the sauce in the pan just has too much mustard?

Comment: Hi Linda, and welcome to the site! Please answer @Jolenealaska's question and give us any other relevant information. This will help us to answer your question better.

Comment: I went ahead and edited this assuming the butter was for sauce, since that's the only thing that really makes sense here. Linda, if you do come back and that's not what you meant, please feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use the butter for this dish. Cordon bleu does not require butter, only cheese and ham.

**EDIT:**

@Joe thinks you mean a mustard sauce to go with the chicken cordon bleu. Is that correct?

OK so in the absence of your verification or any other feedback, the answer is: 
you need increase the other ingredients so the ratio butter : shallot : mustard is back in proportion.

For example the recipe calls for

1 Tbsp butter
1 shallot
2 tsp mustard.

but you put in 4 tsp mustard by mistake?

You increase the butter and shallots so it is all double quantity:

2 Tbsp butter
2 shallots
4 tsp mustard.

1 : 1 : 2

2 : 2 : 4

3 : 3 : 6 etc.

On the other hand you can simply just **ignore the extra mustard**. It may need a little more liquid for the right consistency because there is more starch than usual, but basically the sauce will be just fine. Do not add extra salt before checking the seasoning. The Dijon mustard I use is very salty so I never add any anyhow, but YMMV.

It would be nice if you could acknowledge our various replies, Linda.

Comment: I suspect this was a sauce to to go over the cordon bleu, not inside it.

Comment: Ah, you could be right, @Joe I see no feedback, so presumably Linda H is not interested in dialogue. A shame. I would like to know what happened... :)

Comment: Being new around here, why has a -1 minus appeared next to my answer? OK off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: I have no idea why people downvote.  I try to save it for the *really* bad messages.  I was well under 1% downvotes/upvotes until we had one prolific poster who I thought was posting too many uninformed posts (and then deleting the ones that weren't getting upvoted).  The only think thing that I can recommend is some improved fomatting.  add a '> ', '* ', '1. '  or 4 spaces in front of a line to set things off in different ways, so you don't have to make it all paragraphs.

Comment: The hover text on the downvote says "this answer is not useful" - in practice that usually means the downvoter thinks it either doesn't fully address the question or is wrong in some way. So if the vote appeared before you added in the rest of the answer, it's pretty understandable. Otherwise, dunno - but really, don't worry about it. People are free to vote how they want, and random inexplicable downvotes are never going to win out over the upvotes that decent answers will earn.

Comment: @Joe Jefromi Thanks guys, I will not loose sleep over it. Just curious about the expectations of people who post and then react negatively when someone takes the time to answer. "Nowt so queer as folk," as my granny would say.